# Set up npm global without sudo on osx

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I am attempting to set up node without using sudo on my mac.  I followed this link  http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/.

I already had node on the mac I am using.  So I followed the steps for  **Already Have Node?**

```
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
 sudo rm -rf ~/.npm
```

However, the third step

```
brew uninstall node
```

Is giving me an odd error

```
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/node
```

I checked to see if I have homebrew with

```
brew help
```

I still have it.

It looks like that path is gone.  This seems to be a common link to follow this procedure so I am not sure what I am missing.  Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you do ```brew ls```

Comment: I am getting git mongodb

Answer (score 6):

The way I have overcome this I installed node like normal using brew:

`brew install node`

Then I do:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm`

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules`